# TestContainers SQL too many connections exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, flyway, testcontainers

I am using Spring Boot with 3 SQL datasources defined.
I am using the SpringBoot properties to make the 3 TestContainers for the Datasources.

When I run my tests, the containers are getting slower and eventually I've finally gotten a
`Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Too many connections` exception.

An example test is:

```java
    @Test
    @DisplayName("Require Client Access.")
    @Transactional(transactionManager = "thirdTransactionManager")
    @Sql(
        scripts = "/db/sql/some_test_data_basic.sql",
        config = @SqlConfig(dataSource = "thirdDatasource", transactionManager = "thirdTransactionManager"))
    void requireCustomerAccess() throws CompClientAccessException {

         //Assertions
     }
```

I am using FlyWay to migrate schema so I am unsure if between each test class either Hikari or Flyway is not closing its Connection Pool connections after each method class leading to the too many connections?

I have 3 TestContainers started via Spring's props like below. I can see them in docker.

```
datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:tc:mysql:8.0.22:///databasename?TC_TEMPFS=/testtempfs:rw
datasource.username=dev
datasource.password=password
```

A snippet of the DatasourceConf (one of the three):

```java
   @Qualifier("thirdDatasource")
    @Bean(name = "thirdDatasource")
    public HikariDataSource thirdDatasource() {
        HikariDataSource hikariDataSource = new HikariDataSource();
        hikariDataSource.setMaximumPoolSize(3);
        hikariDataSource.setJdbcUrl(thirdUrl);
        hikariDataSource.setUsername(thirdUsername);
        hikariDataSource.setPassword(thirdUsername);
        hikariDataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
        return hikariDataSource;
    }

    @Bean(name="thirdTransactionManager")
    @Qualifier("thirdTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager thirdTransactionManager(

        final @Qualifier("thirdEntityManagerFactory") LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean thirdEntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(thirdEntityManagerFactory.getObject());
    }
```

I am guessing the HikariPools are being remade for each Test class and not shutting down?

```
 o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper   : HikariPool-45 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30000ms.
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: This is generally due to wrongly using a `DataSource` yourself (obtaining connections and not closing them). However there is basically too little information to answer this question.

Comment: I don't believe anywhere I actively get a connection manually. I rely on the JPA repos. I will keep digging. I may be doing something daft with Flyway...

Comment: Another thing might be if you are using `@DirtiesContext` and/or the container is class based you may end up with more datasources than you think. Which is I suspect the case as  `HikariPool-45` means there are 44 others as well (44 *3 is 136 connections).

Comment: When I use the spring props to create the containers, does that mean the container is reused between all classes or torn down and remade between? I can see the flyway migration scripts re-run each time so I am guessing it's the latter...

Comment: Not sure if they are reused (that is quite test containers specific) but it might as the docker container is already started. The application contexts are cached (so depending on what you run you add new contexts for each test, which is quite slow as well) by default a max of 32. Apparently that is what is happening here because the flyway init is part of the booting process.

Comment: So I have 32 cached contexts with their own 3 Hikari pools basically because I am using Flyway?

Comment: No, because something is leading to additional contexts (probably the `@Sql` which requires new beans).  And you don't have 32 cached contexts as that would yield `HikariPool-96` which you don't so you reach about 16 . Multiple things lead to a (re)creation of an application context, see https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management-caching for things that contribute to a new context being created.

Comment: Oh wow thank you.
I seem to have fallen foul to a few! I have used ActiveProfiles, MockBean etc in various combinations.
So may be able to use DirtiesContext to basically remove that context from the cache so then the extra pools will go?

Also added the logging and yeah:
: `Spring test ApplicationContext cache statistics: [DefaultContextCache@3bf92d96 size = 16, maxSize = 32, parentContextCount = 0, hitCount = 683, missCount = 16]`

Comment: `@DirtiesContext` wil not remove the context, it will reload it instead. But each combination will lead to a new one being loaded and cached. You can control the number of cached contexts you could set it to 4 or 8 instead of 32. Which will close the contexts. BUt you could also check if you really need all those `@MockBean` instances and if everything really needs to be a full integration test with `@SpringBootTest` or that you could use a simpler slice like `@WebMvcTest` or `@DataJpaTest` to name a few.

Comment: Thank you very much.
I mean how do people manage Integration testing in general...because this seems like it could become quite a challenge as more are added?
Or do you just try and minimise the number of contexts/combinations of stuff to try and keep it minimal?
I think I maybe need to check what tests I am running...I think I overlap a lot...
Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to the help from M. Deinum:

Application contexts are cached between tests to help speed up tests:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management-caching

A new context is created say for example a different set of `@MockBean`s are used, different `Profiles` are used.

Due to this, there were more than 16 Hikari datasources cached in my test environment which all at least used 3-10 connections. This was more than the default for the TestContainer so by the time a certain number of tests with differing contexts had been reached/cached, the connection pools (as a sum of ) would not be able to create new connections to the datasource(s) giving the SQL connection errors.

**Takeaway:**

Think about test overlap more. I.e. does it need to be a full `@SpringBootTest` if some logic has already been done or will a `MocMvc` or `DataJPATest` suffice.

The number of cached contexts is 32 by default, but that can be set via a JVM system arg (see docs).

Answer (score 5):

You can also reduce the max size of the cache by creating adding a `spring.properties` file in the test resources directory with the following content:

```
spring.test.context.cache.maxSize=4
```

In this case, the max cache size will be 4 instead of the default 32 mentioned in the docs.

If you're having this problem, it most likely means the cache is not working for you in the first place as a lot of the application contexts are considered unique. So, reducing the size seems expedient.